# Flutter Toast Message not working properly in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, exception, error-handling, toast

`Note: This issue is only with VS Code, works perfectly with Android Studio`

My Flutter Toast message does not work properly, so just to test the flutter toast message with errors or exceptions, I wrote the same email to sign-up, which was already registered in my Firebase. But when I pressed the Sign-Up button, it showed me an error in VSCode instead of showing me on the front-end using the flutter toast message. `(Shown in Picture 1)`

But as soon as I press the `Hot Restart` button on VSCode, it starts showing the flutter toast message on the front-end for a few seconds.

The problem here is, the toast message only appears after I press the `Hot Restart` button, else the toast message never appears.  `(Shown in Picture 2)`

`The way error appears in VSCode:`

[image: Picture of Error]

`Toast Message appearing after I press Hot Restart:`

[image: Toast Message]

`signup_screen.dart`

```
import 'package:firebase/ui/auth/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:firebase/widgets/round_button.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter_flushbar/flutter_flushbar.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';

import '../../utils/utils.dart';

class SignupScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignupScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<SignupScreen> createState() => _SignupScreenState();
}

class _SignupScreenState extends State<SignupScreen> {
  bool loading = false;
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final emailController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();

  // for Firebase Authentication
  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
    // when the screen is gone, then email and password should also be removed/disposed
    emailController.dispose();
    passwordController.dispose();
  }

  void signUp() {
    setState(() {
      loading = true;
    });
    // this is the code to register user Firebase Authentication
    _auth
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: emailController.text.toString(),
      password: passwordController.text.toString(),
    )
        .then((value) {
      setState(() {
        loading = false;
      });
    }).onError((error, StackTrace) {
      Utils.toastMessage(error.toString());
      // Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: error.toString());

      setState(() {
        loading = false;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false, // to remove backbutton
        title: const Text(
          "Sign-up Screen",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ),
        // backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50, vertical: 20),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TextFormField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    controller: emailController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Email",
                      //  helperText: "Please enter your email",
                      helperStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.alternate_email),
                    ),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value!.isEmpty) {
                        return "Enter email";
                      } else {
                        return null;
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    obscureText: true,
                    controller: passwordController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Password",
                      // helperText: "Please enter your password",
                      helperStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock_outline_rounded),
                    ),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value!.isEmpty) {
                        return "Enter password";
                      } else {
                        return null;
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 40,
            ),
            RoundButton(
              title: "Sign up",
              loading: loading,
              onTap: () {
                if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                  signUp(); // calling function made in start
                }
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 30,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                const Text(
                  "Already have an account?",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                ),
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: ((context) => const LoginScreen())));
                    },
                    child:
                        const Text("Login now", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)))
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`utils.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';

class Utils {
  static void toastMessage(String message) {
    Fluttertoast.showToast(
      msg: message,
      toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
      gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      textColor: Colors.white,
      fontSize: 16.0,
      timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the commented code work ? `// Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: error.toString());`

Comment: @BouncyBits nope, that's why I commented it, as it was of no use.

Comment: Could you possibly check using `ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: const Text('snack')));`

Comment: @BouncyBits didn't work